# Moderated Dynamic Word Cloud

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, widget

I was wondering if anyone knew of an app or widget where site users can input words into a word cloud, where the most popular words get bigger. Also, it has to be moderated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, that You could use one of those pretty generators like [WordItOut](http://worditout.com/word-cloud/make-a-new-one) using data gathered from user inputs.

Or maybe You could use application like this:

http://wiki.tcl.tk/17850

Hope it will help You. Cheers.